# how to apply np.power to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dfs. One contains rates, one contains empty values that need to be calculated based on df1-rate table. The two tables look like:

I want to calculate each column from 0 to 2 in df2 by using the following equation 
(1+rate)^(-age)

so my results table should look like this:

```
df1    
             0     1      2       
    rate   0.54  0.45   0.25

df2  
    Age     0     1     2
 0  1       NaN   NaN   NaN
 1  2       NaN   NaN   NaN
 ...
 29 30      NaN   NaN   NaN

results   
     Age          0                1               2
  0  1       (1+0.54)^(-1)   (1+0.45)^(-1)   (1+0.25)^(-1)
  1  2       (1+0.54)^(-2)   (1+0.45)^(-2)   (1+0.25)^(-2)
 ...
  29 30      (1+0.54)^(-30)   (1+0.45)^(-30)   (1+0.25)^(-30)
```

I tried my code

```
y=np.power(1+rate.to_numpy(),-(df.Age))
```

but I got error message:
"operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,6) (30,)"

How can I fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample, you want to broadcast `Age`:

```
np.power(1 + df1.loc['rate'].to_numpy(), -df2['Age'].to_numpy()[:,None])
```

Output (for 3 rows)

```
array([[6.49350649e-01, 6.89655172e-01, 8.00000000e-01],
       [4.21656266e-01, 4.75624257e-01, 6.40000000e-01],
       [2.36798188e-06, 1.44198231e-05, 1.23794004e-03]])
```